# What's it called when a company owns products or services that strictly limit consumers to that company's products or services?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, marketing

What's it called when a company owns products or services that strictly limit consumers to that company's products or services? For example, a camera only saves images in a format readable by a product of the camera manufacturer.

The word or expression I'm looking for would be used like this:

> The way this company imposes such a restriction on its customers is
> called __________.

Comment: i think it might be vertical integration but let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: Proprietary and short-sighted. Customers are past this form of captive love.

Comment: I think it is a form of ***customer retention.*** https://buildfire.com/customer-retention-strategies/#

Comment: One phrase for this is *lock in*.

Comment: google's definition for "lock-in": an arrangement according to which a person or company is obliged to deal only with a specific company.

Comment: "Vendor lock-in" is a more specific name for the same practice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in

Comment: In some cases, this could be a cause of vertical integration, but vertical integration describes a different phenomenon.  Vertical integration is about supply chains and production.  The Ford Motor company needed steel to produce their cars.  Originally, they bought steel that was produced by another company.  But in the 1920s, Ford began producing its own steel to use to make its cars.  That's vertical integration.  This kind of process can result in the phenomenon you describe, but that would be a side-effect of vertical integration.

Comment: An informal term (at least in the context of computing) is "walled garden." Related terms are "closed ecosystem" and "closed platform."

Comment: Do you mean a situation where the purchase of one product or service means that you are obliged in some way to use other products by the same company (for instance that buying a carpet cleaning machine from Acme means that you can only use Acme carpet shampoo with it) or do you mean a situation where only one company provides what you want (for instance only Acme make a carpet cleaning machine for the type of carpet you have)?

Comment: It's a kind of *exclusivity*, without necessarily including the desirable cachet that is often implied by the term.

Comment: Much depends on what precisely it is that limits the consumers to the products of that company. Is it technological difficulties (the products are so complex that no viable competitor has yet emerged)? Is it that some copyrighted software is involved, and the copyright holder has not authorised its copying by anybody else? Is it that the products are protected by a patent? Is it the the company threatens that attempting to combine one of its products with somebody else's products will invalidate the warranty for the former?

Answer (score 2):

Proprietary

'Proprietary systems' or products, limit you to the use of the offerings being created by the 'proprietor' or owner of the company.

For example:

- only proprietary ink cartridges can be used on Epsom printers.
- Apple systems apps are proprietary - they can't be used on other systems

Definition, Merriam-Webster

Definition of proprietary (Entry 1 of 2)
1: one that possesses, owns, or holds exclusive right to something
specifically : PROPRIETOR sense 1
2: something that is used, produced, or marketed under exclusive legal right of the inventor or maker

Comment: While the term proprietary is often used in this way by businesspeople, it should be noted that it is rather vague. It tells us that property rights of some sort are involved, but leaves it unspecified precisely what these rights are (e.g. whether they involve copyright, patents, trademarks, ownership of tangible goods . . .).

Answer (score 1):

**vertical integration**

[Vertical integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_integration) is the combination in one company of two or more stages of production normally operated by separate companies. For example, if I manufacture Widgets and these Widgets are made out of wood, to vertically integrate, I might buy a lumber mill or even forests, and I might also open my own Widget stores so that the only place anyone can buy a Widget is at my Widget store.

Complete [vertical integration](https://knowledge.wharton.upenn.edu/article/vertical-integration-works-for-apple-but-it-wont-for-everyone/) means one company controls the end product as well as all of its component parts, so the company needs to buy nothing from anyone else but rather owns and operates every aspect of production of everything that goes into that product from raw materials through bringing it to selling it to consumers.

**EXAMPLE:**

A quintessential example of a company that completely vertically integrates is Apple, Apple being both famous and infamous for its iron grip on control over every single aspect of its products, from accessories, to software, to literally everything. The first Macintosh computers, for example, were sold as a single unit and couldn't even be cracked open. Everything contained in them and any and all periphery items were completely proprietary, a business model that Apple founder Steve Jobs vehemently insisted on and fought tenaciously to keep, even against his own shareholders, and which in the end proved to be prescient and wise and why Apple still completely vertically integrates even though Steve Jobs has been gone now for years, having died in 2011.

A counterpoint to Apple's total vertical integration is IBM, which did very little to vertically integrate and even made its operating system opensource, resulting in IBM's hardware being undercut in the marketplace by off-brand clones dubbed *IBM compatible PCs* and by IBM's operating system and application software ultimately being supplanted by competitors, chiefly Microsoft, thus IBM is now no longer the chief manufacturer of hardware or software for what was initially its product: the PC.

Through extremely tenacious and even litigious **vertical integration**, Apple has quite effectively avoided the pitfalls that cost IBM nearly all of its market share in every aspect of the PC, IBM's original invention and brainchild, by aggressively maintaining tight control of every aspect of its products.

Answer (score 1):

I think the phrase that best describes it in tech is *a closed ecosystem*, although that might apply to a group of products or an operating system rather than a single product.

Answer (score 1):

A popular but less precise alternative to “vertical integration” from @BenjaminHarman, often applied to Apple®, is:

> **walled garden**

The literal definition of this is horticultural. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walled_garden) has:

> A walled garden is a garden enclosed by high walls for horticultural
> rather than security purposes, although originally all gardens may
> have been enclosed for protection from animal or human intruders.

In this sense it is a positive description — the walls increase the heat and foster growth, and at the same time keep undesirable elements at bay. Definition of its application to information technology technology tends to be coloured by the attitude (often negatice) of writers towards it. It occurs in the [Wikipedia entry for “closed platform”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_platform), for example, but this is prefaced by disclaimer. However, the entry will serve here:

> A closed platform, walled garden, or closed ecosystem is a software system wherein the carrier or service provider has control over applications, content, and/or media, and restricts convenient access to non-approved applicants or content.

As an example of its use I reference a piece by John Thornhill, the (US) tech correspondent of the most reputable British newspaper, [The Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/e4b2ff3b-1fb9-4f6b-837a-ab0368fb7125) (March 18, 2021), which had the headline:

> **Apple’s move to increase privacy strengthens its walled garden**

I will not quote the article, but it appears to be free to view for anyone wishing a more extensive explanation.

Comment: @user405662 You were correct in stating my answer was deficient but incorrect in suggesting it was a comment. Comments are suggestions for improvements or requests for clarification. They are explicitly not for answers which are unsupported , the defect of my own caused by a domestic interruption. I have supplied this now, so you can delete your comment and I this response.